# Attributes on links

Tags: org-mode

In Org we can create a link with the code `[[http://example.com][a website]]`. Translating Org notes to HTML we get the code `<a href="http://example.com">a website</a>`. However, HTML supports attributes that are not included in the Org syntax (e.g., `rel` and `target`). How we can write Org code to generate an HTML code like this `<a rel="me" href="http://example.com">a website</a>`.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to add inline HTML code for the link directly:

```
This is a link @@html:<a rel="me" href="http://example.com">a website</a>@@
added with HTML code.
```